# Why can't I access the LiveMysql namespace even though I added numtel:mysql-server?

Tags: javascript, mysql, meteor, meteor-packages

I am trying to add the following meteor module: [`numtel:mysql-server`](https://github.com/numtel/meteor-mysql) into [Microscope](https://github.com/DiscoverMeteor/Microscope).
I am just doing the steps described on [`numtel:mysql-server` Leaderboard example](https://github.com/numtel/meteor-mysql-leaderboard) such as `meteor add numtel:mysql-server`.

But I can't access any of the variables defined in the Meteor package from inside my code.

I am not doing much just did "meteor add numtel:mysql-server" to the microscope example, server-side :

```
var liveDb = new LiveMysql({
  host: 'localhost',
  //Port 3407 as specified in leaderboard.mysql.json
  //If using external MySQL server, the default port is 3306
  port: 3306,
  user: 'root',
  password: '****',
  database: 'leaderboard'
});
```

Which throws an error with :

> LiveMysql is not a variable.

So I have to do this:

```
var LiveMysql = Meteor.npmRequire('mysql-live-select');
var MysqlSubscription = Meteor.npmRequire('mysql-live-select');
```

Mysql-live-select is a separate npm file which I add and it does not give any error, but I still have problem accessing the database.
But if I do the following on the meteor package :

```
var LiveMysql = Meteor.npmRequire('numtel:mysql-server');
```

I get the following error :

> Cannot find module: numtel:mysql-server

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please share the relevant code, what you were expecting to happen and what actually happened.

Comment: That may be so, but your description is to vague and it is difficult to understand exactly what setup you created and which variables you are trying to access. "just adding some lines" is an infinite options space.

Comment: Sorry I edited the main problem statement...that was by mistake...

Comment: What is the project path of the file in which you try to use `LiveMysql`?

Comment: I tried it in /server/fixtures.js and also made a /main.js file and wrote the code under sever in to microscope example...both did not work.

Comment: The package that provides the reactive MySQL is `numtel:mysql` and not `numtel:mysql-server` (which provides an encapsulated server). If you want to use your own server, you need to configure it according to [the guide](https://github.com/numtel/mysql-live-select#installation).

Comment: This step I tried....I was just wondering about this application called leaderboard https://github.com/numtel/meteor-mysql-leaderboard. It just does this meteor add numtel:mysql-server....Can't I replicate these steps in another meteor application named microscope.

Comment: If you don't have `LiveMysql` on the server (without requiring `npmRequire`), it appears that the package is not installed. You did not indicate that you installed it. Does `numtel:mysql` appear in your `.meteor/packages` file?